# Не записывается Master Boot Record раздел в файл

Tags: c#, mbr

Пытаюсь создать копию MBR записывая её в файл mbr.img:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
IntPtr hTemplateFile);

SafeFileHandle handle = CreateFile(lpFileName: @"\\.\C:",dwDesiredAccess: FileAccess.Read,dwShareMode: FileShare.ReadWrite,
lpSecurityAttributes: IntPtr.Zero,dwCreationDisposition: FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
dwFlagsAndAttributes: FileAttributes.Normal,hTemplateFile: IntPtr.Zero);

using (FileStream disk = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.Read))
{
   byte[] mbrData = new byte[512];
   Console.WriteLine("Starting MBR Backup...");
   try
   {
     disk.Read(mbrData, 0, mbrData.Length);
     FileStream mbrSave = new FileStream("mbr.img", FileMode.Create);
     mbrSave.Write(mbrData, 0, mbrData.Length);
     Console.WriteLine("MBR Backuped to mymbr.img success!");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Ошибок нету, но создаётся пустой файл `mbr.img`

В чём может быть ошибка?

---

P.S: На Windows 7 работает нормально. Пишу на **windows 10**

Пример взял от сюда: [Создания файла Master Boot Record](https://xakfor.net/threads/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-mbr-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E.16241/)

Comment: А чтение-то из MBR нормально происходит?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Да) Я решил проблему, забыл добавить ещё один using в FileStream. Скорее всего файл как-то использовался, поэтому не записывались данные. Теперь всё нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена добавлением using в запись файла:

```
using (var handle = CreateFile(@"\\.\C:", FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero))
{
  using (var disk = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.Read))
  {
     Console.WriteLine(value: "Starting MBR Backup...");
     try
     {
       disk.Read(new byte[512], 0, (new byte[512]).Length);
       using (var mbrSave = new FileStream(path: "mbr.img", mode: FileMode.Create))
       {
         mbrSave.Write(array: new byte[512], offset: 0, count: (new byte[512]).Length);
         Console.WriteLine("MBR Backuped to mymbr.img success!");
        }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       }
    }
}
```